# How can I get the nearest date with given day using date-fns?

Tags: javascript, date, momentjs, date-fns

In my database I have stored a day like "sun", now I am trying to get the nearest day of the week using that day, I got it to work with `moment`

```js
getActualDate() {
  const days = ['sun', 'mon', 'tue', 'wed', 'thu', 'fri', 'sat']
  const date = moment.utc().startOf('day')
  const expectedDay = days.indexOf(this.day) // "sun"

  date.days(expectedDay)

  // If later than given day of the week, move to next week
  if (date.days() < moment().days()) {
    date.add(7, 'days')
  }

  return date.toDate()
}
```

How can I achieve this with `date-fns`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use POJS. The input value should be tested and perhaps should accept a day number as well.

```js
/* Return next instance of day >= today
 * @param {string} day : 3 letter lower case abbreviation of day name
 * @returns {Date} next instance of day that is >= today
 */
function getDay(day) {
  let days = {sun:0, mon:1, tue:2, wed:3, thu:4, fri:5, sat:6};
  let idx = days[day.toLowerCase().substr(0,3)];
  let today = new Date();
  // Zero time and copy today
  let then = new Date(today.setHours(0,0,0,0));
  // Set then to day in current week
  then.setDate(then.getDate() - then.getDay() + idx);
  // If then is before today, add 7 days. Otherwise, return then
  return then < today ? new Date(then.setDate(then.getDate() + 7)) : then;
}


['sun','mon','tue','wed','thu','fri','sat'].forEach(day =>
  console.log(getDay(day).toString())
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this using `isSameDay`, `addDays`, `startOfWeek` and `nextDay`

```js
const getFirstDateFromDay = () => {
  const dayIndex = days.indexOf(day) as Day

  return isSameDay(date, addDays(startOfWeek(date), dayIndex))
    ? date
    : nextDay(date, dayIndex)
}
```

Comment: `days.indexOf(day) as Day` is javascript?